# C# sqlcommand If not exist code error

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand

```
    public void Test2()
    {
        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from Temp_Student", con);
            SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string sql = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT s_name FROM Student WHERE s_name = @chp1) BEGIN INSERT INTO Student(s_name, s_pass) values(@chp1, @chp2) END";

                string test = "";

                SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chp1", test);
                com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chp2", test);
                com1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Currently i am trying to insert data from Temp_student table into Student table, with the exception of duplicates which already exists in Student table. With the current code i don't run into any errors but on my Student table, there is a row of blank values inserted even though currently there is no duplicates.

What i wanted to do was to insert 2 columns from Temp_Student into Students without duplication and currently this is a part of the code where i was passed by another. i do not really understand much of this. If there are other ways please suggest to me too. Thank you

Comment: What are "black values"?

Comment: the variable _test_ is set to a _blank_ value. You check if the value exists or not. If the value doesn't exist you insert a _blank_ value both for user and password, then you repeat the loop until the end of the reader but at this point you have added a _blank_ row. What value do you really want to use for test? I suppose the value of the current record pointed by the reader.

Comment: Nice typo.  Black => blank.  Edited.

Comment: I think @Steve is correct. I would add that this seems like a very convoluted way to go about this. Your code will run `n + 1` queries where `n` is the number of records in `temp_student`. Why not run a single `MERGE` command to do this all at once rather than using an iterative approach?

Comment: As afterwards i am need to prompt the user to ask if they want to update(merge) or delete the duplicate value as such i like to only add the non duplicated values first

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact columns in your table, but you can do this (adjusting for actual columns), assuming that `Student_Name` is your primary key.

```
insert into Student
select 
    tmp.Student_Name, tmp.Student_Pass
from
    Temp_Student tmp
    outer join Student stn on tmp.Student_Name = stn.Student_Name
where stn.Student_Name is null
```

The outer join returns all records in `Temp_Student` whether or not there are matching records in `Student`. When there are no matching records in `Student` the columns selected from that table are null. So by selecting based on this join we return only records in `Temp_Student` that aren't matched in `Student`.

You can also use a [`MERGE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx) statement. A lot of people who were writing SQL before 2008 got used to doing it the "old" way but this is more explicit.

```
MERGE Students AS T
USING Temp_Students AS S
ON (T.Student_Name= S.Student_Name) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET  
    THEN INSERT(Student_Name, Student_Pass) VALUES(S.Student_Name, S.Student_Pass);
```

`MERGE` must be terminated with a semicolon. Technically all statements should be but SQL enforces it on `MERGE`.